# Returning a specific value from a table

Tags: excel, datatables

I want to create a cell which returns the column of a table. The column number should depend on a different variable. How would I do this?

For example,
Cell X

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |

Y = random variable or cell

Cell X should return the Cell 2 if Y=2 and return Cell 1 if Y=1

I have tried a lot of research but all of them show finding a value from matching or looking up.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please clarify the question with exactly what codes you've tried or found, and why they don't work for you. Why can't you use 'finding a value from matching or looking up'?

Comment: @SpencerBarnes I am new sorry, the question is kind of hard to explain. I just want to output a specific value from a table in which the column number is decided by another cell. Matching or looking up does not help me as I dont want to search for a value, instead i am trying to make a cell equal to another value extracted from the table

Comment: So, you want the row number to be either fixed or randomly selected? And you have a specific way of deciding the column number you want?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `=Indirect()`. Like `=Indirect("A" & if(Y=1, 1, 2))` ? You'll have to explain better to say for sure. Recognize that using generic terms like "Cell x" and "Variable" are confusing. Excel is made of cells that are referred to by their row and column. Try to make a simple replicable example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @SpencerBarnes Row number fixed, just want a specific value from that row which depends on column number

Comment: @JNevill Hiya thanks and apologies for my vagueness english isnt my first but no time for excuses. Let me try code u gave.

Comment: @JNevill I did what you said, but I think I need to explain better lol. Basically, I have a table and I want to extract one value of that table. the value should depend on the column number which is equal to a cell called B7 in my spreadsheet, and it should be the bottom row of that table. The extracted value should change depending on B7 changing

Comment: Still feels like Indirect is the way to go. You may need to get creative with `Index()` for solving that "bottom row of a table" part. If it's a legitimate excel table that might look like `Index(YOURTABLE[INDIRECT(B7)], Rows[YOURTABLE])` (as an example). Again a clearer example in your question would help a lot here.

Comment: Why is this tagged as a `datatables` question? If you hover your mouse over that tag, you can read a summary of what the tag means. Please delete the tag if it is not relevant to your question. (It refers to a JavaScript/jQuery library - not to Excel.)

Comment: You can take the [tour] and read [ask] for more guidance on how to write an effective question - one which is more likely to receive helpful answers from the community.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `INDEX()` Function.

In this answer I'm assuming the fixed row number is row 1 (not including the headers row), and that what you describe as

> Y = Random variable or cell

is the value of cell `Y1`

```
=INDEX(Table_Name, 1, Y1)
```

Comment: Just seen your later comment addressed to JNevill - change Y1 to B7 (plus of course insert your own table name) for the above answer to work.